# minimum in Highcharts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So Im using this code to create a highcharts line chart

http://jsfiddle.net/3oLh5r2w/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate from 2006 through 2008'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                    'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minRange: 14 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            },
            floor:1,
            min: 1,
            max: 300,
            reversed: true,
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 1),
            data: [
                83, 28, 253, 113, 72, 177, 279, 71, 228, 72, 54, 162, 275, 246, 111, 119, 225, 19, 244, 102, 1, 75
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

In the Fiddle, Im trying to make it so that the yaxis always shows 1 - 300. The problem I am having is that it is always rounding down to 0. I have tried using startOnTick, but it didnt do anything. The only thing that I could find that made it work correctly was setExtremes, but it could only be activated through an after load function like a click function.

How can I get this to work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case when you set min as 1, you need to have tickInterval which allows to achieve 300. Other solution is using [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions) / [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner)

EDIT:
Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/3oLh5r2w/4/ `tickPositions`

Comment: tickPositions is the way to IMO

Comment: This is actually not what I was looking for. I need the charts yaxis to always show 1 - 300 and no more or less :D

Answer (score 1):

set `startOnTick : false`,

here is the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3oLh5r2w/2/

here is the documentation

The minimum value of the axis. If null the min value is automatically calculated. **If the startOnTick option is true, the min value might be rounded down.**

Comment: This worked for if one of the values is above 10, but can the chart always be 1 - 300 even if all of the points are 300?

Comment: you can try that in jsfiddle, put all the points as 300 and it still works